# Js-jQuery - check if element is focused or get last focused element class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, focus, document

is it possible to check if an element is focused?

i tryed:

```
 <a href="#"></a>
    $('a').is(':focused');
```

but it won't work.

Also i would like to understand if is possible to get the last focused document element attr class:

```
var last_focused_class = document.lastFocusedElement.class;
```

for example

Comment: have you tried `is(':focus')` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)).

Comment: Try `$('a').is(":focus");` instead of `$('a').is(':focused');`

Comment: oh god, this works sorry i reformulating my question so

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were close, to test for focus:

```
$('a').is(':focus');
```

Not sure about how to get the last focused element, you may have to design a hack for it...something like:

```
var lastFocusedClass;
$(document).on('focus', '*', function() {
    lastFocusedClass = $(this).attr("class");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this works... `$("*:focus")`

You can get `id`,`name`,`value` etc.And check if this is the element you are looking for.

```
var checkValue = $("*:focus").attr("...");
```